# Set max attribute for the jQueryMobile slider from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, attributes, slider

I have a slider

```
<div class="slider-container" id="game-mode-slider-container">
                    <label for="game-mode">Game mode</label>
                    <span id="game_mode_indicator" class="slider-indicator">Private</span>
                    <input type="range" name="points" id="game-mode" min="0" value="0">
 </div>
```

Actually I have couple of them on one page. What I want to do is to set max attr from JavaScript.

```
$('.ui-shadow-inset.ui-body-inherit.ui-corner-all.ui-slider-input').is('#game-mode').attr('max', '7');
$('.ui-shadow-inset.ui-body-inherit.ui-corner-all.ui-slider-input').is('#game-mode').slider("refresh");
```

So what I do is I make a selector using class and id both. This doesn't work. If I just use this class it does work, but then I can't have different values for different sliders,because they all have the same class, but different ids. I got this class name using Inspect element in Chrome.

```
<input type="number" data-type="range" name="points" id="game-mode" min="0" value="0" class="ui-shadow-inset ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-slider-input">
```

Can someone please help mi with this.

Comment: $("#game-mode").prop("max", selection).slider("refresh"); works. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/a8zu03L7/ (click radio buttons to change the max of the slider.

Comment: OK, i have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery, set the prop("max") to the new value and then refresh the jQM slider widget:

```
$("#game-mode").prop("max", selection).slider("refresh");
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/a8zu03L7/)**

(click radio buttons to change the max of the slider.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#game-mode').attr('max', '7').slider("refresh");
```

Comment: That doesn't work for some reason :S This worked $('#game-mode.ui-shadow-inset.ui-body-inherit.ui-corner-all.ui-slider-input').attr('max', gameModeValues.length - 1);
        $('#game-mode.ui-shadow-inset.ui-body-inherit.ui-corner-all.ui-slider-input').slider('refresh'); I am sorry I posted the question, but if u edit yours a little bit, I can mark it.